# How to remove Carriage Returns (Line Breaks), but keep original font formatting (color, size, ect)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my cells have fonts with multiple colors and line breaks. I  want to remove all the line breaks from the cells, while keeping the original font colors.

My Cells:
[image]

I've tried <kbd>CTRL+H</kbd> and using <kbd>CTRL+J</kbd> and replace all, but then all words in the cell go to one color.

I also tried using

```
=CLEAN(H4)
```

and

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(H4,CHAR(13),""),CHAR(10),"")
```

Both options create a new column, but neither with original font color

I tried used VBA:

```
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each MyRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
            MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

But it also changed all words within a cell to one color.

Here's another VBA code I tried (recommend in comments by Foxfire And Burns And Burns):

```
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim i As Long
Dim MyText() As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim zz As Long
Dim xx As Long


For zz = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
Set rng = Range("H" & zz)

ReDim MyText(1 To Len(Replace(Replace(rng.Value, Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), 
"")), 1 To 2) As String

xx = 1
For i = 1 To Len(rng.Value) Step 1
    If Asc(Mid(rng.Value, i, 1)) <> 13 And Asc(Mid(rng.Value, i, 1)) <> 10 
Then
        MyText(xx, 1) = Mid(rng.Value, i, 1) 'we save text
        MyText(xx, 2) = rng.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color 'we save color
        xx = xx + 1
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To (xx - 1) Step 1
    rng.Characters(i).Text = MyText(i, 1)
    rng.Characters(i).Font.Color = MyText(i, 2)
Next i
Next zz


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

On the line *ReDim MyText(1* I get *Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range*. From my very limited understanding of code, I tried to access a nonexistent element in an array. I'm trying to debug, but I don't quite understand how the the line works. Sorry, I wish I had a better understanding.

Comment: You can't transfer the color and format from one cell to the other with formulas. You need VBA

Comment: @Kaiser I gave this VBA macro a try: 

Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
    For Each MyRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
            MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
        End If
    Next
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub 

But it also made all words within a cell one color. 

Any ideas?

Comment: If it fails at line `ReDim MyText(1 To Len(Replace(Replace(rng.Value, Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), 
"")), 1 To 2) As String` it means that, at sometime, `Len(Replace(Replace(rng.Value, Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), 
""))` returns a 0 value. Could be that any cell of the range is empty/blank? If yes, you need to adapt the code to skip those blank cells when found. Something like (If Len = 0 then goto ...the end of that For..Next Loop)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Easy way would be like this one (Actually, you can even record a macro and adapt the code to your needs)

I have some text with colors and different fonts in Column A.

[image]

In column B I've used formula `=SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(10);"")`

Then, you can select all cells in column B, and paste them onto Column A but **paste as values!**

[image]

Now you got original text with no linebreaks, and keeping original font and colors.

Simple VBA version of this:

```
Dim i As Long

For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    Range("A" & i).Value = Replace(Replace(Range("A" & i).Value, Chr(10), ""), Chr(13), "")
Next i
```

The code will check every cell in column A, starting at last non empty one, and will remove line breaks, but keeping fonts and colors.

UPDATE: Looks like OP's problem is that in a cell can be some chars in one color and other chars in a different color, and needs to replicate same format, but excluding linebreaks, so the only solution is VBA.

I did some test with junk. As you can see in the image below, I got some texts with different colors in same cell, and 2 of them got linebreaks:

[image]

The code will check every single char in the text, excluding linebreaks. It will create an array bidimensional. First dimension will save the char, and second one will save the color number.

Later on, it will replace the original value in cell with the new one, keeping colors and text, but excluding linebreaks.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim MyText() As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim zz As Long
Dim xx As Long


For zz = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    Set rng = Range("A" & zz)

    ReDim MyText(1 To Len(Replace(Replace(rng.Value, Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), "")), 1 To 2) As String

    xx = 1
    For i = 1 To Len(rng.Value) Step 1
        If Asc(Mid(rng.Value, i, 1)) <> 13 And Asc(Mid(rng.Value, i, 1)) <> 10 Then
            MyText(xx, 1) = Mid(rng.Value, i, 1) 'we save text
            MyText(xx, 2) = rng.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color 'we save color
            xx = xx + 1
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To (xx - 1) Step 1
        rng.Characters(i).Text = MyText(i, 1)
        rng.Characters(i).Font.Color = MyText(i, 2)
    Next i
Next zz

Erase MyText
```

After executing code, I get this in column A:

[image]

No linebreaks, but colors and text is the same than original.

This code will keep **only** the color. If you need to save font name, size, bold or not, and so on, you will need to increase the dimensions of the string array, and save in each dimension what you need.

Hope now you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, my cells have fonts of different colors inside them. I've attached a photo showing what my cells look like. This is a useful idea for the future. Thank you.

Comment: Oh! Then you will have to develop a complex code, because you will need to check every single character code and color, save it, and then returning it

Comment: Understood. I wanted to check with you guys before wasting too much time. I didn't want to overlook any options.

Comment: What would be the best way to change all red font to another color? Will that also be complicated for the same reason?

Comment: @Eggart, to give you an idea refer to this recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232446/partial-text-color-for-multiple-phrases-in-a-cell-when-phrases-are-added-by-data/57232631#57232631) I gave. In the same manner you can split by space char. at Foxfire, sorry for jumping in the comments like that :)

Comment: @JvdV I will. Thank you.

Comment: No problem @JvdV. Eggart, the only problem you got in cells is that some chars got different color? or maybe can a a cell have different font, color and size?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I'm not sure I understand the question. I am trying to make all the red words in the photo (from my post) a different color. I tried the Simple VBA version (mentioned above), but I may have used it incorrectly, because It led to the same problem of all font in a cell going to one color.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I gave it a shot, but I'm getting an Run-time error (I updated my post with more info). I'm not sure how the line with the error works exactly. Do you think my problem is something obvious I missed? If it's a major concept failure on my part, do not feel obligated to spend too much time. I appreciate your help today. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to do it without a macro. 
 All you need is a Texteditor with search & replace and a program to zip and unzip files.

1. Save a copy of your excel.
2. Change the filename extension from your "ExcelName.xlsx" to "ExcelName.zip".
3. After extracting the zip file you can now see the folder structure your Excel is made of.
4. Navigate to ExcelName > xl > sharedStrings.xml
5. The sharedStrings.xml ["contains one occurrence of each unique string that occurs on all worksheets in a workbook"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-the-shared-string-table). So all text used in your excel. Change the filename extension to sharedStrings.txt and open it in your favourite text editor.
6. Now search & replace for "\n" (linebreaks) and replace with " " or whatever you want to.
7. Save > change back to sharedStrings.xml > navigate to uppermost folder structure > rezip everything > change back to ExcelName.xlsx

Now you have an Excel without any linebreaks in the cells, but the contents kept all other formatting. 
You can copy and paste the desired columns/cells without the linebreaks into the Copy of the original Excel (Step 1) with the linebreaks.

Hope this helps future problemsolvers